# How can I map rows from three tables into one entity with NHibernate/FluentNHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate

I've come unstuck this particular problem as I'm still fresh to NHibernate/FluentNHibernate. I will describe the problem in detail but before I do I would like to mention that I am free to change both the domain model *and* the underlying database as I see fit. However I have specific reasons for my current design and would like to stick to it if I can.

I have a User entity. A User has some Preferences, such as their chosen culture ("en-US"/"fr-CA", etc) and their preferred conversion system (Metric/British Imperial, etc). There are other preferences as well, and further preferences can (and will) be added over time. I therefore do not want to represent preferences as columns on the underlying User table. Rather I want the table structure to look like this (pseudo SQL):

```
Table Preference (int Id, nvarchar(50) Description)
Table PreferenceOption (bigint Id, int PreferenceId, nvarchar(50) Value)
Table UserPreferences (int Id, uniqueidentifier UserId, bigint PreferenceOptionId)
```

One Preference (i.e. "Culture") can have multiple preference options (i.e. "en-GB", "fr-CA"). A user's preferences are held in the UserPreferences table which has a foreign key to the PreferenceOption table.

I would like my domain model to look like this:

```
public class User
{
  public virtual Guid {get;set;}
  public virtual Preferences {get;set;}
}

public class Preferences
{
  public virtual CultureInfo Culture{get;}
  public virtual ConversionType ConversionType {get;}
}
```

I imagined that I'd try and load all preferences belonging to a user into a collection (on the Preferences class) and let the properties do the respective conversion into CultureInfo and ConverstionType (a custom enum) respectively.

I'd be really grateful for any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think NHibernate will be able to handle all the corner cases in this situation. What happens if you don't have a preference with the `Id` for `CultureInfo` in the `PreferenceOption` table? What if the `Preference` doesn't exist at all? How does it know to map `CultureInfo` to a specific row in the `PreferenceOption` table? (Is `Description` really a constant that describes which property to populate?)

I think you're asking for trouble. If you want to use a schema like this, I think you'll have better luck with a more direct mapping of your schema to your NHibernate POCOs. You can write some code to populate your `Preferences` object easily enough from the rows of the `PreferenceOption` table related to your user.

Frankly, if you already know that there will be some user preferences, add them to your schema. It's far easier to deal with in many situations (think reporting, etc - at least one less join and more determinism) than having a  "dumping ground" table for essentially untyped, dynamic data.

If you think you'll need it, I'd leave the dumping ground in, in case of emergency. But if you have the flexibility to include the data you **know** you need in your schema during this point in your development, do that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The idea is to be able to add new preferences to the system without having to update all user rows - so defaults would be handled in domain logic if a user doesn't have a specific preference set. Also, the _type_ of preference corresponds to an enum (PreferenceType) which NHibernate can map into the "Description" column and back. If I know the description type I can convert the value of the preference (from nvarchar) to the right type in my domain, i.e. use "en-GB" as a parameter to the CultureInfo class.

Comment: Actually, upon reflection I think you're right. I'm attacking this the wrong way. The underlying data structure is fine, but I'm modelling it wrong. This is what happens when you stare at the same problem for hours. You've helped me see! Thanks very much. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Øyvind, it seems like you'd face the same issue even if you used the `<join table="..."/>` statement in your .hbm.xml. (which, by the way, won't work in your situation anyway since it's a one-to-many.) That is, if you update the schema to add a new column for a user preference, it will be NULL by default and your domain logic could handle that NULL value by substituting the default value. Anyway, if you must use this schema, just map your preferences to another entity and have your `Preferences.<whatever> get { }` property do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Øyvind, glad I could help. (sorry if the above comment doesn't make sense, I posted it before I saw your 2nd reply.)